# crear una columna temporal en sql

Tags: sql-server

Imaginemos el siguiente tengo problema, tengo una tabla donde columna donde tengo "idroles" y "nombre de roles" (la llamaré roles)y estos vinculados por "idroles" a "usuarios" en otra tabla: no todos los usuarios tienen roles, pero de todas formas debo poder ver a todos los usuarios, por eso (me imagino) una columan temporal donde al lado del usuario poner el rol "admin" por ejemplo, tengo multiples tipos de admin en roles pero me interesa saber quienes son admin, sin importar de qué, pero, si este no es admin de nada que ese campo quede vació. no se si se entiende:

lo que me imagino es lo siguiente

```
usuario | roles
-----------------
hugo    | 
paco    | admin
luis    | 
pepe    | admin
otro    |
```

entonces claro me imagno dentro del select hacer un segundo select pero me da conflicto: asi que algo me esta faltando. me puden dar una mano con esto?

Comment: deberías agregar que usas, si mysql o sql server o.....?

Comment: que quiere decir crear una columna temporal? vos queres que en tu select aparezca esa columna? tene en cuenta que un select es solo una vista de una tabla (o mas tablas, o inclusive solo datos que no vienen de tablas), y puede tener todas las columnas que vos quieras mostrar, y con los datos que vos quieras...

Comment: ya añadi que uso sql-server! gracias @BetaM no me di cuenta que nunca lo puse

Comment: Por qué no tiene rol? Ni si quiera un rol usuario? Qué función tienen los que no tiene rol?

Comment: @gbianchi yo quiero que el resultado del select que hago para saber los admin poder volcarla en algún lado, el detalle es que no quiero perder la cantidad de usuarios ya que es mayor a la cantidad de roles por eso me imagine una columna temporal y en ella definiría con `CASE when` o algo de eso

Comment: no entiendo.. vos queres crear otra tabla? o queres una consulta que devuelva eso? entiendo la query y es un simple left join, ahora, mas alla de eso, que estas buscando? probaste alguna query? no existen las columnas temporales en ninguna base de datos.. pero las columnas se crean solas al hacer un select...

Comment: es un ejemplo @Bicho todos tienen algun rol, pero solo quiero dejar visible quien es admin: el resto no tiene por que aparecer (el caso real es mucho mas complejo por eso tire esto en el aire).

Comment: probaste un left join y no te funciono? que fue lo que probaste?

Comment: @gbianchi quiero que la consulta me devuelva eso

Comment: probe con un left join pero no me funciono por que tengo usuarios que tienen mas de un rol: y yo antes hago una suma de sueldo (cobran un monto por cada rol que desempeñan) cuando hago el left join un usuario me aparece 3 veces (por ejemplo) y eso hace que el sueldo se divida en 3. pero eso es otro tema largo por eso queria ver si se podia hace eso en una consulta. si no sigo probando

Comment: Complicado añadir o aportar sin saber cómo están creadas las tablas y cuáles fueron las consultas que probaste. No hay mejor forma de contarnos eso que editar la pregunta y añadir esa información. Ojalá como texto por si necesitamos replicar tu problema

Answer (score 2):

para obtener los admin de la tabla roles, hariamos (ponele)

```
select idroles, rol from roles where nombre = "admin"
```

Ahora, para obtener todos los usuarios con su rol, pero solo mostrar los admin, hariamos

```
select nombre, rol from
usuarios u left join (
    select idroles, rol from roles where nombre = "admin") r
    on u.idroles = r.idroles
```

Este query, conecta las tabla usuarios con una vista de la tabla roles que solo tiene los admin. Luego de eso, usa un left join que trae todas las filas de la izquierda, sin importar si hay datos en la fila de la derecha.

Answer (score 0):

Si no entiendo mal, tienes 2 tablas. Una de roles y otra de usuarios. En los usuarios tienes un campo idRoles que existe en la tabla roles.

Lo que quieres es que al hacer una consulta de la tabla de usuarios te devuelva el nombre del rol, no el id. Es así?

Si ese es el caso lo que necesitas son las `JOIN`. Hay diferentes tipos de `JOIN`. Si quieres que siempre salga el usuario pese a que no tenga un rol lo que necesitas es una `LEFT JOIN`.

Un ejemplo sería:

```
SELECT u.nombre, r.nombre
FROM Usuario u LEFT JOIN Rol r ON u.idRol = r.idRol
```

Hay 4 tipos de join (que tenga yo en mente). La diferencia entre ellas es como tratan el caso de que no exista información en una tabla.

`LEFT JOIN` siempre mostrará los datos de la tabla de la izquierda aunque no exista un registro en la derecha que haga match en la condición `ON`
`RIGHT JOIN` es lo mismo pero al contrario. Mostrará los registros de la derecha exista o no dato en la izquierda
`INNER JOIN` solo mostrará los datos si existe un registro en ambas tablas
`FULL OUTTER JOIN` si hay un match en cualquiera de las dos tablas devolverá los registros

Como bola extra, es importante tener en cuenta que los `JOIN` no son de lo mas eficiente que hay. Por lo que siempre hay que estar atento por que columna se hace un join y probar si un índice mejora la performance.

Answer (score -1):

Si he entendido bien tienes la tabla **Rol(IDRol, RolDescripcion)** y **Usuario(IDUsuario,Nombre IDRol)**. Creo que si la cunsulta que quieres hacer la vas a realizar mas veces, lo mejor seria crea una vista, para la siguiente `select`.

```
Select Nombre, RolDescripcion from Usuario inner join Rol on Usuario.IDRol = Rol.IDRol
```

Comment: si se usa inner join, los nombres que no tengan rol no van a salir en esta query. Por que mejor no esperar a que OP clarifique su duda?

Comment: Tienes razon, posiblemente para lo que el quiere lo mejor sea un Left join.